# PDO and dynamic request doesn't work

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have the following code :

```
$sth = $dbh->prepare('SELECT COUNT(*) as size FROM `users` WHERE uid  = :uidVal');
$sth->bindValue(':uidVal', $_POST['uid'], PDO::PARAM_INT); 
// $_POST['uid'] == 2147483647
$sth->execute();
$size = $sth->fetchAll();

print_r($size);
```

The print_r() return :

> Array ( [0] => Array ( [size] => 0 [0] => 0 ) )

But this is my data base (mysql)

[image]

I don't understand why my `COUNT(*)` return 0, normally it should return 3?

**EDIT (based on the comments)**

This is my code after the select statement :

```
    $stmt = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO `users` (uid, uname) VALUES (?, ?)");
    $stmt->bindParam(1, $uid);
    $stmt->bindParam(2, $name);

    // insertion d'une ligne
    $name = $_POST['uname'];
    $uid = $_POST['uid'];
    $stmt->execute();
```

Why into my data base the uid value is `2147483647` while the uid value in my $_POST is `10152434954117198`

Comment: @Linger its in the code.

Comment: Double check `$_POST['uid']`

Comment: @Debflav i waiting for one result yes, the count(*)

Comment: @r3tep are you sure there is nothing wrong in your PDO Statement?

Comment: @R3tep: var_dump($_POST) and show us the output.

Comment: Make sure the value is 2147483647

Comment: @Abhijeetyadav Nothing wrong

Comment: there's no user with uid 10152434954117198. That's why the count is 0

Comment: @R3tep The answer is that you set the wrong POST value for uid in the form.

Comment: also, i smell integer overflow here....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The uid value is to big for my data base configuration :

[image]

`10152434954117198` is a long not an integer

Answer (score -1):

Try this code.

```
$sth = $dbh->prepare('SELECT COUNT(*) as size FROM `users` WHERE uid  = ?');
$sth->bindValue(1, $_POST['uid']); 
// $_POST['uid'] == 2147483647
$sth->execute();
$size = $sth->fetchAll();

print_r($size);
```

OR you can try this too

```
$sth = $dbh->prepare('SELECT COUNT(*) as size FROM `users` WHERE uid  = :uidVal'); 
// $_POST['uid'] == 2147483647
$sth->execute([
    "uidVal" => $_POST['uid']
]);
$size = $sth->fetchAll();

print_r($size);
```